# What is a three-pronged LED?

Tags: led, diodes, identification, components

I've used two-pronged LEDs and Diodes, but I've come across a three-pronged one:

[image]

What is this component called, and how would it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two-colour LED that either share anode pins or cathode pins. That's why 3 pins instead of four.

Comment: Typically a red and green LED, turn on both, you get yellow.